# ¿Cómo evitar que el teclado aparezca automáticamente en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app con un `EditText` quiero evitar que el teclado aparezca automáticamente al rotar la actividad.

Noto que no se comporta de la misma forma el EditText en `portrait` como en `landscape`.

El `EditText` lo tengo establecido multi-linea y está dentro de un `HorizontalScrollView` y `ScrollView`

```
ScrollView
   HorizontalScrollView
        EditText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade en el `EditText`:

```
editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

O bien puedes hacerlo por configuración en tu manifest:

```
<EditText
    ... Tus definiciones
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" 
/>
```

Comment: el modo en hacerlo en manifest, en la aplicación o la activity?

Comment: @Webserveis En la definción del `EditText` que seguramente tendrás en el activity. Ahora edito respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Existen varias soluciones.

La primera aplica si no requieres que tu Activity se vuelva a construir, definela en AndroidManifest.xml como:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

La segunda es que otra vista tome el enfoque mediante `android:focusable="true"`, como en este caso el contenedor:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_ll"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/my_edittext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

La tercera que yo uso regularmente es agregar en la definición de la actividad la propiedad `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` :

```
 <activity
  ...
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
  ...
  />
```

Ahora veo una cuarta, usando el flag [flagNoExtractUi](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)

> **flagNoExtractUi** Puede desactivar el modo de entrada FullScreen con
>   flagNoExtractUi en el atributo android: imeOptions

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi" 
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

La opcion y solucion mas facil para poder resolver este problema es agregar lo siguiente dentro de tu android manifest el cual cambiara el estado del teclado a oculto y evitara que aparezca al dar clic sobre el elemento:

```
<activity android:name="NombreActividad" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adaptado la respuesta de @Miquel_Coll

Detecto si la App corre en una tableta y así quito el modo edición pantalla completa, si no solo cuando se muestre en horizontal, oculto el teclado, pero permitiendo la edición pantalla completa.

```
if (GeneralUtils.isTablet())
    textArea.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
else if (GeneralUtils.isLandscape())
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```